# Remove white space created by relative placed div OR place div's on top of each other while preserving scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox, css-position

I have a pretty specific website design in which I place horizontal bars over a date/time scale. The date scale needs to scroll horizontally while I'm also able to vertically scroll through the bars.

I have the following codepen to show the situation: [codepen](https://codepen.io/oehoe83/pen/MWXOxPq)

The hScroll div needs to scroll horizontally. the content div needs to scroll vertically.

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">   
    <div>HEADER</div>  
  </div>
  <div class="hScroll">
    <div class="dates">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="bars">
        <div></div>
        <div class="wk"></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="overlay">
        <div style="top: 20px; left: 200px;"></div>
        <div style="top: 400px; left: 1200px;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The css

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
  height: 45px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #3c5db2;
  color: rgb(240,240,240);
}
.hScroll {
  display: flex;

  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.dates {
  display: flex;
  width: 2000px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(66, 133, 244);
}
.dates > div {
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  border-right: solid 2px rgb(240,240,240);
  color: rgb(240,240,240);
}
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 2000px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 3em
}
.bars {
  display: flex;
}
.bars > div {
  width: 200px;
  border-right: solid 2px rgb(240,240,240);
  height: 1000px;
}
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  top: -1000px;  
}
.overlay div {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: red;
}
.wk {
  background-color: rgb(220,220,220);
}
```

Is there a way to create the same result without using "position: relative"?

If not, how to fix the white (in this case green) space at the end of content div?

With all the scrolling going on and the precise positioning of the bars it's hard to find a fitting solution on the web. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: where is white space

Comment: In this case "grey space". If you scroll down vertically all the way in the content div.

Comment: I edited the codepen to show the unwanted space as green.

Comment: this is due to overlay class

Comment: try below answer hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like below,

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
  height: 45px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #3c5db2;
  color: rgb(240,240,240);
}
.hScroll {
  display: flex;

  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: rgb(0,255,0);
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.dates {
  display: flex;
  width: 2000px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(66, 133, 244);
}
.dates > div {
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  border-right: solid 2px rgb(240,240,240);
  color: rgb(240,240,240);
}
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 2000px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 3em
}
.bars {
  display: flex;
}
.bars > div {
  width: 200px;
  border-right: solid 2px rgb(240,240,240);
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  top: -1000px;  
}
.overlay div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: red;
}
.wk {
  background-color: rgb(220,220,220);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">   
    <div>HEADER</div>  
  </div>
  <div class="hScroll">
    <div class="dates">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
      <div>8</div>
      <div>9</div>
      <div>10</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="bars">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="wk"></div>
        <div class="wk"></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="overlay">
        <div style="top: 20px; left: 200px;"></div>
        <div style="top: 100px; left: 400px;"></div>
        <div style="top: 200px; left: 700px;"></div>
        <div style="top: 300px; left: 900px;"></div>
        <div style="top: 400px; left: 1200px;"></div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It's funny. In my original project I didn't wrap the absolute positioned divs in the overlay div. That's why the scrolling was broken when I changed the position to absolute. Thanks for you time!